# Divisibility Proof Help

Tags: divisibility

Show that for all integers $j$, if $d$ is an integer such that $j \mid k+8$ and $d \mid k^2+1$ then $j \mid 65$.

I'm having a lot of trouble, with solving this proof. I first rewrote the equations as,

$$\begin{align*}
aj &= k + 8, \\
bj &= k^2 + 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Then by adding them together,

$$\begin{align*}
aj + bj &= k^2 + k + 9, \\
(a+b)j &= k^2 + k + 9.
\end{align*}$$

But I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\!\bmod d\!:\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv -8}\,$ so $\,0\equiv \!\overbrace{f(\color{#c00}n)}^{\textstyle n^2\!+\!1}\!\equiv \overbrace{f(\color{#c00}{-8})}^{\textstyle 65}\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with integer coef's, by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Comment: It's a modular form of: $\,x\!-\!a\,$ and $\,f(x)\,$ have a common root $\iff f(a) = 0\,$ (here $\,a=-8)\ $

Comment: Are congruences or modular arithmetic already known?

Comment: As in the linked dupe $\,d\mid f(n),\,n\!+\!8\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid f(n)\bmod n\!+\!8 = f(-8)=65\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

From $d \mid n + 8$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& n + 8 \equiv 0 \pmod d \\
& n \equiv -8 \pmod d \\
& n^2 \equiv 64 \pmod d \\
& n^2 + 1 \equiv 65 \pmod d
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $d \mid n^2 + 1$, from \eqref{eq1A}, you get $n^2 + 1 \equiv 65 \equiv 0 \pmod d \implies d \mid 65$.

Answer (score 0):

$d \mid (n+8) \Rightarrow d \mid (n+8)^2$

So: $d \mid (n^2 + 16n + 64) \tag{1}$

Also: $d \mid (n^2 + 1) \tag{2}$

So $d$ divides this difference:

$d \mid (n^2 + 16n + 64) -  (n^2 + 1) \Rightarrow d\mid (16n + 63) \tag{3}$

Now since $d \mid (n+8)$ we get:

$d \mid 16(n+8) \tag{4}$

$d \mid (16n+128) \tag{5}$

Finally from $(5)$ and $(3)$ we get that $d$ divides this difference:

$(16n+128) - (16n + 63) = 65$

Comment: This proof is correct, it shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: Usually, to denote that "$a$" divides "$d$", you write $a \mid d$ *not* $a / d$. Note the use of the LaTeX command "\mid" (or "|" if you're lazy and don't care about spacing). I'm not the person who downvoted your proof.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I understand how to approach to the question now

Comment: @Lenehan Yeah, the approach is first get rid of the $n^2$ term, then of the $n$ term which means you will be left with just a number (65 in this case).

Comment: Denote $t = gcd(n+3, n^2+1)$. Take $(n+3)$ to power $2$. Then $t$ 
divides $(n+3)^2 - (n^2+1) = 5n+5$. So $t | (5(n+1))$ 
Can you go on from here? $5$ does not divide $(n+3)$ because it divides $n$. 
The same argument applies to the number $2$. 
So $5$ and $n+3$ are coprime and so $5$ and $t$ are coprime. 
So $t | (n+1)$. But also $t | (n+3)$. So... $t | 2$ 
Now again obviously $t$ cannot be $2$ so $t$ must be $1$.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @peter.petrov Note you stated in your comment above that $(n+3)^2 - (n^2 + 1) = 5n + 5$, but actually it's $6n + 8$ on the right side instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I really liked the approach of using congruences and modular arithmetic to this question, just wondering if a similar methodology can be applied to part 2?

Comment: @Lenehan The concept of congruences and modular arithmetic can basically always be applied to questions like yours, although it's not always necessarily the easiest or best method to use. However, in your case, let $d = \gcd(n + 3, n^2 + 1)$. Then $n + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod d \implies n \equiv -3 \pmod d \implies n^2 + 1 \equiv 9 + 1 \pmod d$. This means $d \mid 10$. However, since $10 \mid n$, then $10 \not\mid n + 3 \implies d \not\mid n + 3$ &, thus, $d = 1$, i.e., $n + 3$ & $n^2 + 1$ are coprime. Also, you can use the Polynomial congruence rule as member "gone" suggested in a question comment.

Comment: @Lenehan You're welcome for the explanation. However, I didn't explain the end part properly. I should have stated something like that since $d \mid 10$ and $10 \mid n$, then $d \mid n$. Since $\gcd(3,10) = 1$, then if $d \gt 2$, you have $d \not\mid n + 3$. However, since $d = \gcd(n + 3, n^2 + 1)$, then $d \mid n + 3$, so the only possibility is $d = 1$, i.e., $n + 3$ and $n^2 + 1$ are coprime. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: Simpler: $\,d\,\mid\, n^2\!+\!1-(n\!-\!8)(n\!+\!8) = 1\!+\!8^2.\,$ More conceptually $\bmod d\!:\ i:= n\,$ is a sqrt of $\,-1$ so $\,0\equiv \omega := i-8\,\Rightarrow\,0\equiv \omega\,\bar\omega = 65\ $ @Lenehan